# Python's unidecode alternative for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unicode, ascii

Is there any JavaScript/TypeScript alternative that works similarly to unidecode library for Python? (Converts Unicode characters to ASCII)
https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

E.g.

```py
>>> unidecode('kožušček')
'kozuscek'
>>> unidecode('30 \U0001d5c4\U0001d5c6/\U0001d5c1')
'30 km/h'
>>> unidecode('\u5317\u4EB0')
'Bei Jing '
```

Comment: Have you tried [`unidecode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unidecode)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much. I have no idea how I could not find it on Google. You can post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. @Konrad

Comment: That library may work, but it doesn't offer much evidence of being actively maintained.

Comment: Library requests are off topic on SO. Please see the [help].